# Как заполнить ArrayList только определенными данными?

Tags: java, android, list

Не знаю как  правильно сформировать вопрос, начну по порядку.
В файле `strings.xml` есть данные. `cat` - это категории, `titleString` - заголовки

strings.xml

```xml
<string-array name="cat">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="titleString">
        <item>Аист</item>
        <item>Акула</item>
        <item>Акула-молот</item>
</string-array>
```

Второй файл `Person.java`

```
public class Person {

    long id;
    String title;
    String cat;

    // пустой конструктор
    public Person() {
    }

    // конструктор с переменными
    public Person(long id, String title,  String cat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.cat = cat;
    }
}
```

Подключаем ресурсы

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);
String[] cat = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat);
```

Теперь, как можно заполнить `persons` только данными где `cat` равно 1 например.

```
// этот код заполняет `persons`, можно ли заполнить не всеми данными, а только теми где `cat` = 1 
int length = title.length;
persons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    persons.add(new Person(i, resurs.title[i], resurs.cat[i]));
}
```

Comment: Почему не использовать блок `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void inflatePersons(String cat) {
    int length = resurs.title.length;
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (resurs.cat[i].equals(cat)) {
            persons.add(new Person(i, resurs.title[i], resurs.cat[i]));
        }
    }
}

//заполнить только если cat = 1
inflatePersons("1");
```

Comment: Все отлично работает. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Artsait, не за что! :)